# Liquibase library fails with Nullpointer in Micronaut 2.0

Tags: java, docker, micronaut

I have a Micronaut 2.0 app with micronaut-data (postgresql) and liquibase.
When I run app in IDEA or local jar, it works fine. App has several migrations and when it runs in docker only the first executes successfully, then it fails with error:

```
app_1  | 06:40:33.937 [main] INFO  liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor - 
 CREATE TABLE public.marker_type (id SMALLINT GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY NOT NULL, name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL, title VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL, description VARCHAR(100), CONSTRAINT MARKER_TYPE_PKEY PRIMARY KEY (id), UNIQUE (title), UNIQUE (name))
app_1  | 06:40:33.948 [main] INFO  liquibase.changelog.ChangeSet - Table marker_type created
app_1  | 06:40:33.953 [main] INFO  liquibase.changelog.ChangeSet - SQL in file sql/20200715-1712-create_marker_type_table.sql executed
app_1  | 06:40:33.955 [main] INFO  liquibase.changelog.ChangeSet - ChangeSet classpath:db/migrations/change-log.yml::20200715-1712-create_marker_type_table ran successfully in 18ms
app_1  | 06:40:33.956 [main] INFO  liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor - SELECT MAX(ORDEREXECUTED) FROM public.databasechangelog
app_1  | 06:40:33.961 [main] INFO  l.lockservice.StandardLockService - Successfully released change log lock
app_1  | 06:40:33.963 [main] ERROR io.micronaut.runtime.Micronaut - Error starting Micronaut server: Bean definition [javax.sql.DataSource] could not be loaded: null
app_1  | io.micronaut.context.exceptions.BeanInstantiationException: Bean definition [javax.sql.DataSource] could not be loaded: null
app_1  |    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.initializeContext(DefaultBeanContext.java:1540)
app_1  |    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultApplicationContext.initializeContext(DefaultApplicationContext.java:220)
app_1  |    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.readAllBeanDefinitionClasses(DefaultBeanContext.java:2768)
app_1  |    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.start(DefaultBeanContext.java:228)
app_1  |    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultApplicationContext.start(DefaultApplicationContext.java:166)
app_1  |    at io.micronaut.runtime.Micronaut.start(Micronaut.java:64)
app_1  |    at ru.vinguardsoft.ApplicationKt.main(Application.kt:9)
app_1  | Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
app_1  |    at liquibase.util.LiquibaseUtil.getBuildInfo(LiquibaseUtil.java:45)
app_1  |    at liquibase.util.LiquibaseUtil.getBuildVersion(LiquibaseUtil.java:17)
app_1  |    at liquibase.sqlgenerator.core.MarkChangeSetRanGenerator.generateSql(MarkChangeSetRanGenerator.java:91)
app_1  |    at liquibase.sqlgenerator.core.MarkChangeSetRanGenerator.generateSql(MarkChangeSetRanGenerator.java:25)
app_1  |    at liquibase.sqlgenerator.SqlGeneratorChain.generateSql(SqlGeneratorChain.java:30)
app_1  |    at liquibase.sqlgenerator.SqlGeneratorFactory.generateSql(SqlGeneratorFactory.java:222)
app_1  |    at liquibase.executor.AbstractExecutor.applyVisitors(AbstractExecutor.java:25)
app_1  |    at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor.access$600(JdbcExecutor.java:40)
app_1  |    at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor$ExecuteStatementCallback.doInStatement(JdbcExecutor.java:384)
app_1  |    at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor.execute(JdbcExecutor.java:59)
app_1  |    at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor.execute(JdbcExecutor.java:131)
app_1  |    at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor.execute(JdbcExecutor.java:111)
app_1  |    at liquibase.changelog.StandardChangeLogHistoryService.setExecType(StandardChangeLogHistoryService.java:388)
app_1  |    at liquibase.database.AbstractJdbcDatabase.markChangeSetExecStatus(AbstractJdbcDatabase.java:1130)
app_1  |    at liquibase.changelog.visitor.UpdateVisitor.visit(UpdateVisitor.java:64)
app_1  |    at liquibase.changelog.ChangeLogIterator.run(ChangeLogIterator.java:83)
app_1  |    at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:202)
app_1  |    at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:179)
app_1  |    at io.micronaut.liquibase.LiquibaseMigrationRunner.performUpdate(LiquibaseMigrationRunner.java:189)
app_1  |    at io.micronaut.liquibase.LiquibaseMigrationRunner.migrate(LiquibaseMigrationRunner.java:146)
app_1  |    at io.micronaut.liquibase.LiquibaseMigrationRunner.run(LiquibaseMigrationRunner.java:109)
app_1  |    at io.micronaut.liquibase.LiquibaseMigrationRunner.lambda$null$0(LiquibaseMigrationRunner.java:91)
app_1  |    at java.base/java.util.Optional.ifPresent(Optional.java:183)
app_1  |    at io.micronaut.liquibase.LiquibaseMigrationRunner.lambda$onCreated$1(LiquibaseMigrationRunner.java:91)
app_1  |    at java.base/java.util.Optional.ifPresent(Optional.java:183)
app_1  |    at io.micronaut.liquibase.LiquibaseMigrationRunner.onCreated(LiquibaseMigrationRunner.java:88)
app_1  |    at io.micronaut.liquibase.LiquibaseMigrationRunner.onCreated(LiquibaseMigrationRunner.java:62)
app_1  |    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.doCreateBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:1945)
app_1  |    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.createAndRegisterSingletonInternal(DefaultBeanContext.java:2635)
app_1  |    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.createAndRegisterSingleton(DefaultBeanContext.java:2621)
app_1  |    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.loadContextScopeBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:2163)
app_1  |    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.initializeContext(DefaultBeanContext.java:1538)
app_1  |    ... 6 common frames omitted
```

The second run of app has an error:
`relation marker_type already exists`

If downgrade Micronaut to v1 and don't change other code then app runs without problem in docker.

What's wrong in Micronaut 2?

UPD:

`application.yml`'s fragment:

```
datasources:
  default:
    url: 'jdbc:postgresql://${DB_HOST:localhost}:5432/demo'
    username: 'postgres'
    password: '1234'
    driverClassName: 'org.postgresql.Driver'
jpa:
  default:
    entity-scan:
      packages: 'models'
    properties:
      hibernate:
        hbm2ddl:
          auto: none
        show_sql: true
liquibase:
  datasources:
    default:
      change-log: 'classpath:db/migrations/change-log.yml'
```

`DB_HOST` is environment in docker-compose.

UPD:
`docker-compose.yml`

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      args:
        JAR_FILE: build/libs/mdemo*-all.jar
    ports:
      - "8090:8090"
    depends_on:
      - db
    environment:
      SERVER_PORT: 8090
      DB_HOST: db
  db:
    image: postgres:12
    expose:
      - "5432"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: 1234
      POSTGRES_DB: demo
```

Comment: Did you try to recreate the container ?
`docker-compose up --force-recreate`

Comment: Yes, I tried. The same behavior

Comment: Please share your docker-compose file.
What is your version of Liquibase ?

Comment: Added docker-compose to question. Liquibase is latest: implementation("io.micronaut.liquibase:micronaut-liquibase") - 2.0.0

Comment: As per my answer within micronaut is liquibaseVersion=3.8.0 , please check the posted workaround

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you have hit following issue.

https://liquibase.jira.com/browse/CORE-3468

The workaround is

```
shadowJar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Bundle-Version': 'UNKNOWN'
        attributes 'Build-Time': 'UNKNOWN'
    }
}
```

Micronaut is still using version 3.8.0 of liquibase
https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-liquibase/blob/master/gradle.properties#L8

After library upgrade is completed you will not hit it anymore https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-liquibase/issues/74 but it will be released with version 2.1 of Micronaut.

Answer (score 0):

Could you share you application.properties or application.yaml in your resources folder?

I believe that your datasource isn't configured, could be the general one or the one in flyway.

I can imagine that you rely on env vars in that config but you didn't provided those on container startup.

Comment: Added to question post. If datasource were not configured than no one migration will be done at all, right? I did nothing changes in application.yml or docker files when I changed Micronaut's verion.